# How to verify whether a browser exists in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriver to open a Firefox browser and iteratively pass a URL to it using a spreadsheet (that contains 5 URLs in different cells of column 1).
Now if suppose i manually close the firefox browser after two URLs were opened. I want my script to handle this situation and continue the execution for which i tried the below three conditions, however everytime i get a Null pointer exception.
Please suggest how to handle this situation.

```
if (driver.toString().contains("null"))
if (driver.getTitle().contains("null")) 
if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("null"))
```

Comment: try `if (driver != null)` ... to avoid the NPE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method for that However you can use this as a workaround

```
/**
 * 
 * @return true if driver is alive else false
 */
public Boolean isAlive() {
    try {
        driver.getCurrentUrl();//or driver.getTitle();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: then accept it as answer as it will be helpful for others

Comment: i want to but i cant since, i don't have reputation of 15 as of now. :)

Comment: upvote is different from accept you have to jus click on the tick button and everyone has the privelage to do so